Make Google Scholar find public access versions of indexed articles
Google Scholar helpfully nags me about providing public access versions of my articles in order to fulfill their funding mandates. Unfortunately, it sometimes indexes the restricted-access version of my article without finding the corresponding public access version, and I don't see any way of telling it about the existing public access version.  Instead, I see only an option to upload a PDF.
I would prefer not to upload the preprint to Google Scholar, as I don't want to have to maintain multiple versions of the public access preprint.  It's also nice for people citing my work if there's only a single preprint with a single DOI, rather than multiple possibly inconsistent and possibly DOI-less versions.  (Of course, I'd rather they cite the official published version, but they may not always have access to it.)
For instance, here's one of the entries in the "Not available anywhere" section of the public access page in my Google Scholar profile:

Following the "REVIEW" link pops up the following dialog:

And then following the "MAKE A CORRECTION" link reveals the following form:

The form allows me to specify a reason for not uploading the article, but "a public access version of the article already exists on the web" is not among them.  In this case, a public access preprint of the article, with its own DOI, has existed on Zenodo since 1 September 2020.
Is there any way of telling Google Scholar about the existing public access preprint in a way that will (a) allow visitors to my profile to click through to their choice of the official published version or the public access preprint, and (b) dismiss the public access nag message?  Would it suffice to manually add the public access preprint to my Google Scholar profile as a new article, and then merge the new entry with the old one?  Or is there an easier/better/alternative way?

Update on 2024-10-24: It seems the real problem here is that Google Scholar only selectively indexes Zenodo.  Some background and discussion on why this is the case and why the issue probably won't be resolved soon can be found in this issue report for the Journal of Brief Ideas, a journal that publishes through Zenodo.
